# Error on Inherit Startup in ASP.NET Core 2.1 Functional Tests

Tags: c#, functional-testing, asp.net-core-2.1

I created a project functional testing in ASP.NET Core 2.1 and xUnit. I have a function `CreateServer()` like this:

```
public TestServer CreateServer()
{
    var path = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(TScenarioBase))
        .Location;
    var hostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseContentRoot(Path.GetDirectoryName(path))
        .UseStartup<IntergrationTestStartup>();

     return new TestServer(hostBuilder);
}
```

My class `IntergrationTestStartup` like this:

```
public class IntergrationTestStartup: Startup
{
    public IntergrationTestStartup(IConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration)
    {

    }
}
```

and **IntergrationTestStartup** is inherited from **Startup** class from main project.
But I got 404 not found when execute any test case. When I replaced **IntergrationTestStartup** by **Startup**, it worked as expected, But I cannot customize Startup class for test environment.

Please help me to use class **IntergrationTestStartup** in functional testing environment.

Thanks,

Comment: Read the more recent documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Thanks, But I follow the tutorial that not use WebApplicationFactory. Do you have any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. During TEST execution i need to use the DocumentRepositoryMock service instead of DocumentRepositoryApiProxy. The registration in Startup class is:

```
serviceCollection.AddScoped<IDocumentService, DocumentRepositoryApiProxy>();
```

and my test code is:

```
[TestInitialize]
public virtual void TestInitialize()
{
    ...
    ...

    this.Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();

    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseContentRoot(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
        .UseConfiguration(this.Configuration)
        .UseEnvironment(Extensions.HostingEnvironmentExtensions.IntegrationTest)
        .UseStartup<TestStartup>();

        this.Server = new TestServer(host);
        this.HttpClient = this.Server.CreateClient();
```

My TestStartup class inherit from **Startup** and override a method where i make a different service registrations based on the TEST execution:

```
serviceCollection.AddScoped<IDocumentService, DocumentRepositoryMock>();
```

However, the HttpClient used in my test return 404.

I found this solution:

```
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseContentRoot(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
        .UseConfiguration(this.Configuration)
        .UseEnvironment(Extensions.HostingEnvironmentExtensions.IntegrationTest)
        .UseStartup<TestStartup>();

        host.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddScoped<IDocumentService, DocumentRepositoryMock>();
        });
```

Using **ConfigureTestServices** i can registered my *Mock* service and have it injected in my consumer class, **without the need of extend my Startup class**.

In any case, if you can add a the second registration                 services.AddScoped<IDocumentService, DocumentRepositoryMock>() for your test, this will work. Infact having two registration for the same interface, the IoC will give you the last one registered.